# Will incinerators clear out landfills?

Tags: cities-skylines

Will incinerators clear out landfills?  I know you can empty landfills, but I cannot tell if it just goes to another landfill, or if you can burn it off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a landfill is set to being emptied, and you have a working incinerator, then yes, it will slowly clear out the landfill. Keep in mind that incinerators are slow to process garbage, and that you'll still need to handle your city's new garbage as it's produced.